# How to edit Safari form values?

Tags: safari, auto-complete

I would like to be able to selectively edit specific auto-fill form values in Safari - rather than just delete the entire form data for that site.

I know I can do the latter from Prefs > AutoFill > other forms > Edit… but I'd rather be able to remove only the the oddities my errant typing appears to have generated, rather than the actually useful auto-fills I already have in there.

As an example, from the Edit panel in Ask Different itself, I appear to have several aborted versions of "Formatting". I would rather have just the 'correct' entries.

[image]

A guess would be that the data resides in ~/Library/Safari/Form Values but that file seems to be either encrypted or perhaps binary - I can't tell which.

OS X 10.10.4 Safari 8.0.7

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's system-wide. You can use this feature in TextEdit and other text editors by pressing ESC while the cursor is at the end (or middle, but that's weird) of an unfinished word (or finished if you're in the middle).

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359937/decrypt-safaris-form-values-file/360000

Comment: @Arc676 it is definitely NOT system-wide. these form values are per-user, and reside at the ~/Library/Safari/Form Values file

Answer (score 2):

~/Library/Safari/Form Values is a plist file, but it's encrypted with AES-128. The encryption key is stored in the System Keychain as Safari Forms AutoFill.

You can decrypt this file with the decryption tool found here:

- http://encase-forensic-blog.guidancesoftware.com/2013/06/safari-form-values-decryptor.html
- [Decrypt Safari's Form Values file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/359937/decrypt-safaris-form-values-file/360000)

Comment: Sounds scary - the site for sfvd was down all yesterday, so I'll have a look today… fingers crossed; though you wouldn't anticipate removing a couple of typos to be quite this much work ;-) [I know, security, I might have my bank passwords in there too…]

Comment: Hmmm… it appears I can decrypt & edit, but I can find no way to re-encrypt to put it back in Safari

Comment: @Tetsujin- Not just scary - stupid. Who in right mind would upload private data that may contain important personal information - which you don't know since it is encrypted - on to an unknown web-site? especially site focusing on breaking encryption...

I wish there was some other tool I could download and use locally for decrypting this file.