# Is it autofill, or does it have another name?

Tags: safari

Putting it out there to solve a problem which has blighted me for some years now.

Once upon a time, i entered my email address wrong in a form in Safari.

Now I get a little blue text pop-up having a close X to the right with my wrong email address (it happens to be missing the first letter of my first name). If I type the @ symbol, then it kindly fills in my wrong email address. I have to click the X to dismiss this pop-up, and then Autofill kindly does the domain.com bit for me.

Here's (hopefully) an image of the problem in action:

[image: my partial email address with the little blue tooltip showing]

It should be simple to fix by googling the right term and following some clear instructions, if only I knew what it was called.

I've done the usual things like making sure Autofill (Safari/Preferences/Autofill) is using the correct Contacts card for me, and this helps to a degree in that Autofill will then prompt me to enter the correct email address.

I even tried using System Preferences>Keyboard>Text to create a system wide substitution preference, but this sadly doesn't work.

And the real killer, it has somehow followed me for several years from Mac to Mac, which makes me think it is linked to an iCloud setting or preference.

If you know what it's called and can point me at a fix, I'll be very grateful.

Comment: Have you tried `Keychain Access.app`. You should be able to delete the wrong entry.

Comment: Hi Dave. Have you looked at [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/198287/how-to-edit-safari-form-values) and tried to edit the values? Also, if you could edit your post to explain what version of Safari has the issue? Safari for iOS and/or Safari for PC/Mac? You say Mac to Mac in the bottom of the post - but being very clear about the specific scope might help us help you.

Comment: Wondering if it might be in the spelling dictionary? Edit in Terminal: cd Library/Spelling. Then pico LocalDictionary. See if that is in that file, if so delete it and save the file. If not, well... sorry

Comment: So it isn't Keychain Access (i think). Keychain store usernames and passwords for visited websites. This problem is occurring for brand new, never before visited websites.

Comment: bmike, thanks for that link. Looks promising, but I don't have time to test the theories espoused there. Will look into it soon, and vote for your response if it proves to be the magic bullet. I'm talking about Safari 9.0.3 running on my Mac OS 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

Comment: Steve Chambers - thanks again for your response. Sadly, no votes for you, although the clarify of your simple response was appreciated. It was a doddle to navigate to the LocalDictionary file and use pico to edit it, however the specific misspelling I was looking to eradicate wasn't there. My hopes are pinned on bmike's link . . .

Comment: Ooh - bmike appears to be onto something - the same behaviour does occur in Textedit - and keyboard shortcut joy - pressing escape (Esc) dismisses the pop-up, allowing my hands to stay focussed on the task of typing. And happy days, Esc also works in Safari. Now I just need to decrypt ~/Library/Safari/Form Values plist file and see if I can eradicate the problem for good. An update in a few hours. . . .

Comment: Okey dokey. Took a vacation and got distracted without successfully decrypting the plist file in question (~/Library/Safari/Form Values).Turns out the linked Safari Form Values Decryptor utility is no longer available at http://tinyurl.com/nvtlu6k which is a real shame. The website does provide a handy overview of the problem space and links to Apple's documentation on the CSMA encryption toolset. I might build my own, and will post the results online for others to benefit from, although don't hold your breath as I have a steep learning curve ahead of me.